# How can you hide a button from another form

Tags: c#, forms

I have a C# project that has 2 forms. The first has 3 buttons. I need to be able from the second form to hide 2 (button1 and button2 )buttons with a checkbox, and I don't know how to call the buttons from the first form.

this is form1

```
namespace test1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();

        frm.Show();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

and this is Form2

```
namespace test1
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.checkB;

        if (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            ?????????
        }
      }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.checkB = checkBox1.Checked;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to pass the form as the "owner" in the Show() command:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.Show(this); // pass Form1 reference in to our instance of Form2
}
```

In Form2, cast the Owner property back to Form1 so you can access it (assuming you've changed the modifiers property of the buttons to public as already suggested):

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkBox1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.checkB;

    if (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        Form1 f1 = (Form1)this.Owner;
        f1.button1.Visible = false; // or whatever your buttons are called
    }
}
```

This is almost exactly what I had posted previously...you need to change the Modifiers property of the buttons so they are public and can be seen from Form2.

Comment: thanks for the answer i tried and it give me error and i do not want that Form1 to create Form2

Comment: What error did you get? What are your form names?  Which form creates which?  Give us some details, please; we can't magically see the rest of your code...

Comment: thanks for the help I posted the code I'm sorry I did not give more details

Comment: "and i do not want that Form1 to create Form2"   Lol...that's exactly what you're doing in your posted code.  I'll put an example up soon.

Answer (score 1):

this is the final version that works in my case thanks to those who answered my question and helped me to get this answer

Form1

```
namespace test1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.checkBox1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.checkB;

        if (frm.checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            button1.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.Show(this); 
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Form2

```
namespace test1
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.checkB;

        if (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            Form1 f1 = (Form1)this.Owner;
            f1.button1.Visible = false; 
        }
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.checkB = checkBox1.Checked;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
}
```

The buttons and checkBox are set to Modifiers - Public

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the buttons on the first form public and then you can access them once you create a instance of the first form you will need to pass that form to the second form.

Comment: hi i try this and don`t work the button is public if (btClienti.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                Main fr = new Main();
                fr.button1.Visible = true;
                
            }

Comment: no you can't make a new instance you need to pass the 1st form to second forms constructor post the code when you create the second form

Comment: hi i try to find something as you said but i was not successful please can you give me an example or a link where can i read about this

Comment: Post your code of making the second form and showing it

Answer (score 0):

Might want to look into building an event that fires from one form and gets handled by the other form to disable the button.